# How to add a default method for an action class of a grammar?

Tags: grammar, raku

Recently, I experimented with some grammars for modifying small parts of a
 file. In those test cases, I would keep much
of the file as it was, only modifying small pieces here and there, see
[this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/189123/33560) review question for an example.

So I needed one (or a few) action methods (i.e. methods in the action class of the
 grammar) where I would attach the modified parts of the file to the
 match object using its 
make method. The problem was that the grammar itself would have many more
token/rules/regex with complicated
nesting. Hence, there was a need to propagate (by successively calling
 `make()`) the small change (currently attached to
 a token's match object) up to the `TOP()` method in the action class
such that everything 
 else (all other tokens/rules/regexes) in the file was kept untouched
 in the result returned from the grammar's `.parse()` call.

So all methods in the action class except for one, was on the exact same form:

```
method make-data ($match-data) {
    $match-data.make( [~] $match-data.chunks.map: {$_.value.?made // $_.value} );
}
```

Now, this explicit repetition of the same code for all action methods seems
to me very verbose, and also breaks with the DRY programming principle.

Is there a way to tell the grammar class that if an action method
(corresponding to a token in the grammar) is
not specified , it will default to the `make-data` method above (or a similar one)?

So in this case, I envision a `DEFAULT()` method in the action class:

```
method DEFAULT ($match-data) {
    $match-data.make( [~] $match-data.chunks.map: {$_.value.?made // $_.value} );
}
```

that is called if a token in the grammar class does not have a
corresponding method in the action class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perl 6's Type system will call a [FALLBACK](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#Fallback_method) method, if it's present in a class and an unknown method call is made.

The following solution adds default construction methods to the `Calculations` actions class.

```
grammar Calculator {
    token TOP { [ <add> | <sub> ] }
    rule  add { <num> '+' <num> }
    rule  sub { <num> '-' <num> }
    token num { \d+ }
}

class Calculations {
    method ws($) {}
    method FALLBACK($token, $match-data) {
        $match-data.make( [~] $match-data.chunks.map: {
            $_.value.?made // $_.value;
        } );
    }
}

say Calculator.parse('2 + 3', actions => Calculations).made;
```

Comment: It's probably neater to just do the logic directly in the `FALLBACK` method rather than calling `add_method`. I'm guessing this was done with performance in mind, but it may well make things worse unless `self.^compose` is called to install an updated method cache.

Comment: Have edited the answer and removed the self.^compose. Logic is now directly handled in the FALLBACK method.